# Snowflake DDL created is wrong with ' execute immediate create view '

Tags: sql, view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ddl, execute

**Query:**

```
execute immediate '<--create view query-->';
```

**Resultant DDL:**
*create or replace view view_name(
<--columnlist-->
) asexecute immediate '<--create view query-->';*

***Example:***
**Query:**

```
execute immediate 'create or replace view a as select * from b';
```

**DDL:**
*create or replace view a(b1,b2,b3) asexecute immediate 'create or replace view a as select * from b';*

Comment: Whats your question? Can you please be a bit more concrete?

Comment: Query:    execute immediate 'create or replace view a as select * from b';

Comment: Resultant DDL:   create or replace view a(b1,b2,b3) asexecute immediate 'create or replace view a as select * from b';

Comment: @Jyotirmay Are you executing this from Snowflake UI or how? I just did a test and the query history shows the correct statement.

Comment: I see what you mean now, the get_ddl shows indeed the output you mentioned but it works fine when selecting from the view, so not sure what the problem is exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Well spotted. To reproduce this case using Snowsight:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace view a as select 1 AS c';
-- View A successfully created.

SELECT * FROM a;
-- C
-- 1

SELECT GET_DDL('VIEW', 'PUBLIC.A');
```

> create or replace view A( C ) **asEXECUTE IMMEDIATE** 'create or replace view a as select 1 AS c';

---

Workaround. Using anonymous block to wrap view definition:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
  create or replace view a as select 1 AS c;
END;
$$;
-- null

SELECT * FROM a;
-- C
-- 1

SELECT GET_DDL('VIEW', 'PUBLIC.A');
```

> create or replace view A( C ) as select 1 AS c;